# Position div outside of parent

Tags: html, css

I have some elements that I want to show some additional information when they are hovered on. I have tried positioning my content out of the bottom of the box and then setting it to the bottom on hover, but depending on the amount of content, it sometimes still is visible.

In the example below, I have a red box, which I want the yellow box to animate up from the bottom of. Now I could use a crazy value like `bottom: -9999px` but this will then cause issues with the speed of my animation to slide the content up.

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}
.item:hover .item__box {
  bottom: 0;
}
.item__box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100%;
  background: yellow;
  transition: all 300ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  
  <br /><br /><br />
  <p>lorem ipusm</p>
  <br /><br /><br />
  
  <div class="item__box">
    <p>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </p>
    <p>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </p>
    <p>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </p>
    <p>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </p>
    <p>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make sure that the content is always just outside of the bottom of the box and then slides up nicely on hover?

Edit: Sorry, to make it clear, on hover I want the yellow content to be from the bottom of the red box, so there is a gap at the top where red can still be seen.

Comment: have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp), there are a lot of cool example including the one your looking for (see [slide in](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_slidebottom))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using just top and bottom, which are relative to the parent size if you specify a percentage, you can add [`transform: translate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) to move the element relative to its own size.

This way, you can move the element to `bottom: 0`, which is the final position you want it in (with the bottom of the box aligned with the bottom of the item), and then translate it 100% down, which means that the top of the box will be where the bottom would otherwise be.

The animation doesn't happen on the `bottom` property, but on the `transform`, which means that you essentially move the top of the box from that bottom line to the final position that you get where bottom = 0.

Hard to explain, easy to view:

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}
.item__box {
  bottom: 0; /* Bottom of box aligned with bottom of item */
  /* Starting position: use transform shift the item down by its 
     own height, so it is just out of visible range. */
  transform: translate(0, 100%); 

  transition: all 300ms;
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
}
.item:hover .item__box {
  /* Animation: rather than animate top, animate the translation, so
     it moves up from just out of range to its normal position */
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  
  <br /><br /><br />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <br /><br /><br />
  
  <div class="item__box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
    <p>This is the end!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Personally, I think the effect is even better when the yellow box is smaller than the red item. In that case, it slowly animates in and sticks to the bottom (with, of course, all its contents visible).

Comment: I didn't realise the height was coming from the parent's height, which was confusing me. Unfortunately though, I want the yellow box to be stuck to the bottom when being hovered, while yours is sticking it to the top. If you remove a paragraph from the yellow box then you can see what I mean.

Comment: @SamWillis Didn't notice that, but that rules out the original solution using `top`. I've changed the solution to use `translate` rather than `top`. I've tried to explain what's going on as well, but the example may be more clear than the explanation. ;)

Comment: Awesome, I've never thought to use translate for this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wish to show additional content on hover, have you thought about using an accordion instead?

This can be done manually, using a combination of javascript, html and css.
Or you use a pre-made library plugin like jQuery UI
this can be found at https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: "simply, jQuery".. How is loading over 100KB of JavaScript simpler than writing 3 lines of CSS?

Comment: @GolezTrol , i merely meant rather than scrolling how he was now he could have an accordion. Only offering an alternative solution.

Comment: It looks like the use case here is rather a pop-over hint with information, like for instance a bit of explanation that appears over a picture. Accordion is usually more suitable for multiple pages of information where you can select the right page using the accordeon control. But with a bit of creativity you can use it here as well, of course.

Comment: @GolezTrol the question has been edited, the original post the OP had it on hover and it showed large amount of text and scrolled, so that was my reason for suggesting using an accordion. Now it has been edited, a tooltip / overlay may be more useful.